# setting a tab bar controller view controller programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

Is there a way to set the view controller on the tab bar controller programmatically? Lets say I want it to show the second's tab view controller programmatically, is there a way to do that?

This is useful if I logout from my app, which is done from my third tab, when the user logins it should start from the 1st tab again. When I logout I am just showing a present modal view controller on top of what the previous view is, so I somehow needs to reset it again to the first tab bar without re-initializing it all over again.

The issue is now how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [reference on UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller). Work with selectedIndex and selectedViewController.

Comment: Broken link, please fix or expand the answer

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it looks to me like you could just call the following two functions:

```
    [myTabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    [myTabBarController setSelectedViewController:[myTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi ye you can do this

You might have tabbarcontroller object in appDelegate.

So on logout button

make object on your appDelegateClass and do this:-

```
appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;
```